React Next JS Firebase onAuthStateChanged is not a function
I have another page where the registration of an account works and redirects the page to this, but I get the following error:
TypeError: (0 , firebase_util__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1_.getModularInstance)(...).onAuthStateChanged is not a function
I'm using the firebase version 11.0.1 and I've followed the firebase documentation
'use client'
import Image from "next/image";
import styles from "./page.module.css";
import Dashboard from "./DashBoard/page";
import LoginPage from './auth/LoginPage/page';
import {auth} from './firebaseConfig'
import {onAuthStateChanged } from 'firebase/auth'
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

export default function Home() {

  const [isAuthed,setIsAuthed] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
      if(user){
        setIsAuthed(true);
      }
    })
  }, [])


  return (
    <div>
      {isAuthed?(<Dashboard/>):
      (<LoginPage/>)}
    </div>
  );
}

I tried reading the documentation but it doesen't work on my project
// Import the functions you need from the SDKs you need
import { initializeApp,getApps } from "firebase/app";
import { getFirestore } from "firebase/firestore";
import { getAuth } from "firebase/auth";

// TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
// https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries

// Your web app's Firebase configuration
const firebaseConfig;

// Initialize Firebase

let app;
if (!getApps().length) {
  app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
} else {
  app = getApps()[0];
}

//const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

const auth = getAuth(app);
const db = getFirestore(app);

export default {db,auth};

